# How to decrease the size of a label in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, label, size

I want to decrease the size of a label in tkinter python.

the code:

```
from tkinter import *

top = Tk()
top.title("...")
top.geometry("200x200")

name = Label(top,text="Type Here: ").place(x = 20,y = 50)
e = Entry(top).place(x = 100, y = 50)
name1 = Label(top,text="Type Here: ").place(x = 20,y = 100)
e1 = Entry(top).place(x = 100, y = 100)

top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to decrease the font size:

```
name = Label(top,text="Type Here: ", font=("Courier", 11)).place(x = 20,y = 50)
```

just specify a font and a font size

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width and height of a label like this

```
name = Label(top,text="Type Here: ", height=100, width=100)
name.place(x = 20,y = 50)
```

And you can change it with

```
name.config(height= new_height, width= new_width)
```